# Grokking the basics of BlockChain with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, encryption

As I was [streaming](https://twitch.tv/aaronchall) I had a brilliant visitor suggest we write a blockchain in Python.

So we did.

Note that there is no validation or voting simulated here.

Here's the results, in `package/blockchain.py`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
# https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
from oscrypto.symmetric import aes_cbc_pkcs7_encrypt as encrypt # type: ignore


class Node:
    __slots__ = 'prior_node', 'data', 'hash'
    prior_node: Node
    data: bytes
    hash: bytes

    def __init__(self, prior_node, key, data):
        self.prior_node = prior_node
        self.data = data
        if prior_node is None:
            init_vector = bytes(16)
        else:
            init_vector = _ensure_byte_length(prior_node.hash, 16)
        key = _ensure_byte_length(key, 32)
        self.hash = encrypt(key, data, init_vector)[1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Node<{self.data}\n{self.hash}\n{self.prior_node}>'

def _ensure_byte_length(bytes_, length):
    return bytes(bytes_.ljust(length, b'\x00')[:length])

class Chain:
    __slots__ = 'nodes'
    def __init__(self, key: bytes, data: bytes):
        self.nodes = Node(None, key, data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Chain:\n{self.nodes}'

    def new_node(self, key, data):
        self.nodes = node = Node(self.nodes, key, data)
        return node

    def __len__(self):
        length = 0
        nodes = self.nodes
        while nodes:
            length += 1
            nodes = nodes.prior_node
        return length

def main():
    chain = Chain(b'the key', b'here is a bit of data')
    chain.new_node(b'P@$$w0rd', b'and here is a bit more data')
    chain.new_node(b'hunter2', b'and finally here is some more')
    print(chain)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here's a tiny test, `tests/test_blockchain.py`:

```py
from package.blockchain import Chain


def test_blockchain():
    chain = Chain(b'the key', b'here is a bit of data')
    chain.new_node(b'P@$$w0rd', b'and here is a bit more data')
    chain.new_node(b'hunter2', b'and finally here is some more')
    assert len(chain) == 3
```

Note that we did require oscrypto and openssl to run this.

Ran coverage with pytest under Python 3.7. Ran with black and mypy as well.

Comment: Have you edited this since you ran the code through black? Because black uses `"` for string literals, and would change your inline comment to be PEP 8 compliant. Also it would add 2 empty lines between your top level functions and classes.

Comment: @Peilonrayz silly me, I'm using nix-build and it's running black on the build directory and not the source... I should have known something was wrong with it when I didn't notice changes...

Answer (score 2):

1. By default mypy doesn't test much. This is because a large part of its philosophy is to allow dynamic and statically typed code at the same time. This is so migrating to mypy is easier and less daunting. Having thousands of errors when you start to port your legacy app is likely to scare a fair few mortals away.

   Please use the `--strict` flag to have typed Python, rather than hybrid Python.

   When you use the flag and you type all the functions and methods, you'll notice that there's an issue with `Node.prior_node`. Currently it's assigned the type `Node`, but we know that's a lie because we have `if prior_node is None`.
2. I personally use `--ignore-missing-imports` rather than ignoring each import, as they quickly build up over time.
3. Your `__repr__` are [non standard](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

   > Called by the [repr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned.

   You probably want to be using [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).
4. I find it a little confusing that `init_vector` is being assigned two different things. It would make more sense if you pass in an empty bytes to `_ensure_byte_length`.

   ```py
   prior_hash = b'' if prior_node is None else prior_node.hash
   init_vector = _ensure_byte_length(prior_hash, 16)
   ```

   You could change the ternary into a `getattr`.

   ```py
   prior_hash = getattr(prior_hash, 'hash', b'')
   ```
5. I would change `Node` to a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). Why write code when you can just not?

   This would require moving the hash generation into a class method.
6. I would define an `__iter__` method on the node so that we can easily traverse the chain from any node.

   This makes the `__len__` method of `Chain` really simple and clean.
7. I'd rename `_ensure_byte_length` to `_pad`. The function has two jobs, pad is well known and allows us to have a much shorter function name.
8. `_ensure_byte_length` doesn't need the extra `bytes` call.
9. The method `Chain.add_node` is un-Pythonic. In Python it's standard to return nothing from a function with mutations.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import dataclasses
from typing import Optional, Iterator

from oscrypto.symmetric import aes_cbc_pkcs7_encrypt as encrypt


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Node:
    prev_node: Optional[Node]
    data: bytes
    hash: bytes

    @classmethod
    def build(cls, key: bytes, data: bytes, prev_node: Optional[Node] = None) -> Node:
        prev_hash = b"" if prev_node is None else prev_node.hash
        hash = encrypt(_pad(key, 32), data, _pad(prev_hash, 16))[1]
        return cls(prev_node, data, hash)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Node]:
        node: Optional[Node] = self
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.prev_node


def _pad(bytes_: bytes, length: int) -> bytes:
    return bytes_.ljust(length, b"\x00")[:length]


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Chain:
    node: Node

    def add_node(self, key: bytes, data: bytes) -> None:
        self.node = Node.build(key, data, self.node)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return sum(1 for _ in self.node)


def main() -> None:
    chain = Chain(Node.build(b"the key", b"here is a bit of data"))
    chain.add_node(b"P@$$w0rd", b"and here is a bit more data")
    chain.add_node(b"hunter2", b"and finally here is some more")
    print(chain)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: 1. thx. 2. thx. 3. you quoted "<...some useful description...>" - I do that, and `__repr__` is a fallback for `__str__`. 4. will consider 5. maybe, what about `__new__`? 6. thx 7. pad, no, this will truncate - pad doesn't. 8. thx 9. eh, set returns self on mutating. I really don't like the `Node.build` - will `__new__` work? What about `__post_init__`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing - thanks for putting so much effort into reviewing - +1

Comment: @AaronHall 3. Please re-look at `Chain.__repr__`. No `__repr__` isn't a fallback for `__str__` it's a fallback for `str`. They achieve very different things. 7. Seems pedantic at the cost of nice usage. 9. Right and exceptions define the norm. Whatever. 9.b. New and post may work for you.

Comment: @AaronHall 3. I think you failed to read "If this is not possible". 9. I made the mistake of trusting rando's on the internet. No, [set doesn't return self](https://pastebin.com/mSrbHTp6). Only the special i-op dunder methods do.

Comment: I had the recollection that sets were a source of inconsistency in that area, I wonder where I got that from.